# IE automation wrongly point to maxthon browser

Tags: internet-explorer, automation, maxthon

I use following statement to do IE automation in Window 10:

```
Set WebBrowser1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

The call in the vb6 IDE launches internet explorer correctly.
However, the compiled exe launch maxthon browser instead. How can I fix this?